# Ordem aleatória com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Eu gostaria de traduzir a seguinte instrução SQL para uma expressão *lambda*:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbPessoa order by NEWID()
```

O que coloco no `OrderBy` que será aceito?

```
var pessoa = contexto.tbPessoa.OrderBy(???).FirstOrDefault()
```

Obs: a tabela tem mais de 3000 registros, então idealmente isso não deve ser feito em memória.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o [`Guid.NewGuid()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Guid_NewGuid):

```
var pessoa = contexto.tbPessoa.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/RandomOrder.cs).

Comment: Deu certo. Achei que iria ser bem complicado, e se tivesse algo, teria que ser em memória. Me surpreendi com a solução simples.